# Is there a Probability Distribution or Math Concept that can help solve this problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Problem:**
Let us say you have a set of $T = ({a_1, ..., a_n})$ objects. These different objects can interact with one another such that each pair has a unique probability associated with it. $P(a_j,a_k) = P(a_k, a_j) = x$ would indicate that if all of these objects were interacting with one another at the same time (at the same "concentration"), $x$ percent of the interactions would be between $a_j$ and $a_k$.

Now, let us take a subset of these objects $ S= (a_1, ..., a_l)$ such that $l < n$. These objects will also interact. Can I **predict** (some distribution could work that resembles the problem) the $P$ for each of there $l$ objects given the information in the previous section?

One idea I had: (1) We know that the $\sum P(a_j,a_k) = 1$ for all $a_j, a_k$ in $S$. If we know the relative frequencies of the elements of $S$ from the $T$ set then we can create a new distribution from that information that sums up to 1. I am pretty sure this is invalid since it does not account for the fact that the relative frequencies of interactions may change now that elements are removed from the sets.

Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: When in the second paragraph you say again "Suppose these objects are allowed to interact.", it implies to me that they don't necessarily do so the same way when these objects belonged to the set $T$. I suppose that is not your intention though.  Finally two questions: are self-interactions allowed and are $(a_j,a_k)$ and $(a_k,a_j)$ counted as different interactions or the same?

Comment: I have updated the question, my apologies, To summarize: $(a_j, a_k)$ and $(a_k, a_j)$ are the same interaction. They will interact in the same way as in set $T$ but the $P$ values will have changed.

Comment: If $(a_j,a_k)$ and $(a_k,a_j)$ are the same interaction, am I correct to assume that in point (1) you really mean that $\sum_{j<k} P(a_j,a_k)=1$. I'm sorry to say so, but I feel that your update did not answer any of my questions. Can you provide more motivation/background for the problem. I'll just say this, which may or may not help you: what is relevant is not the set of objects $T$ or $S$, but the set of allowed interactions before and after reduction. Let's call them $T'$ and $S'$ resp. The sum of probabilities $\sum_{(a_j,a_k) \in S'}P(a_j,a_k) < 1$ because you dropped interactions.

Comment: So, to construct a new probability function, define $P'(a_j,a_k) = P(a_j,a_k) / \sum_{(a_j,a_k) \in S'}P(a_j,a_k) $ when $(a_j,a_k) \in S'$.

Comment: I am a biologist studying the interaction of different DNA regions that have specific binding potentials ($x$). I have a dataset that gives me the binding potential of different DNA molecules Example: AAAT ($a_j$), TTTC ($a_k$) binds 2 / 1000 events. I want to use this data to create models that help me study the interaction of subsets of these DNA fragments. You are correct that I mean $\sum_{j , k} P(a_j, a_k) = 1$

Comment: I think it would be better for the clarity of your exposé to first present the biological side of it, before presenting what you think is the correct mathematical formalization of it. Because I suspect you're on the wrong track for the latter part.